# What are these codes in javascript source?

Tags: javascript, html, encode

I looked at page source for a website and I saw a bunch of codes like:

\u0d2a\u0d41\u0d24\u0d41 ....

There are pages of these codes inside the javascript code.

What are these?

Comment: Those are unicode characters.  Most likely for localization, that is language translations of the website content.  Example, [/u0d41](http://graphemica.com/0D41)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are Unicode escape sequences.

You can read more about them here: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode.